# How to Execute an SQL Anonymous Block in DB2?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, db2, db2-luw

I want to make a search through a schema of columns whose data includes 'ABC'. In Oracle PL/SQL, I would do it like this:

```
DECLARE
  v_cnt integer;
BEGIN

  for i in (select tabname, colname
              from all_tab_cols --syscat.columns
             where tabschema = 'DATA'
          order by tabname, colname)
  loop 

    execute immediate '
    select count(1)
    from '||i.tabname||'
    where upper('||i.colname||') like ''%ABC%''' into v_cnt;

    if v_cnt > 0 then 
      dbms_output.put_line(i.tabname||' - '||i.colname)
    end if;

  end loop;

END;
```

However it is in an DB2 database. I have tried search online for the correct syntax, but I cannot find it. syscat.columns is the oracle equivalent for all_tab_cols, so I just need the correct syntax for an anonoymous SQL block in DB2.

Would anyone help me with the syntax, please?

Comment: What DB2 version and platform?

Comment: The version is DB2 v10.5.0.5

Comment: @Fermin -- DB2 can run on many different platforms -- you need to include that information too.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, DB2 for LUW offers *Oracle compatibility mode* -- if it is enabled for your database instance you can simply use Oracle PL/SQL syntax as is and it will work, including the reference to `all_tab_columns`.

If Oracle compatibility is not enabled, the DB2 SQL PL syntax is a bit different. Specifically, `DECLARE` goes *inside* the `BEGIN ... END` block, and you need to `CALL` the stored procedure `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE()`.  Everything else should probably work OK.

More information on the [*compound SQL syntax*](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0004239.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, who konws:

```
BEGIN ATOMIC
DECLARE v_cnt integer;
DECLARE text VARCHAR(128);
DECLARE stmt STATEMENT;

  for i as (select tabname, colname
              from all_tab_cols --syscat.columns
             where tabschema = 'DATA'
          order by tabname, colname)
  do 


--According to Graeme Birchall this shouldn't work  
--        execute immediate '
--        select count(1)
--        from '||i.tabname||'
--        where upper('||i.colname||') like ''%ABC%''' into v_cnt;
-- db2 maybe more verbose:

   set text = 'select count(1) from '||i.tabname||' where upper('||i.colname||') like ''%ABC%''';

PREPARE stmt FROM text;
EXECUTE stmt INTO v_cnt;

        if v_cnt > 0 then 
          dbms_output.put_line(i.tabname||' - '||i.colname)
        end if;

      end for;

    END;
```